How can I unban myself from a discord server my bot is in?
I'm trying to unban my own account using a bot within the same Discord server.
How can I do it?

user = bot.get_user(...)
guild = ctx.guild    # or bot.get_guild(id)
await guild.unban(user)

I'd like to highlight that this does seem like a violation of the developer TOS.
